# Deleting specific functions from java file from the command line without editing

Tags: java, command-line, edit

I am generating Java code from Haxe code and I want to strip down the generated java files.
This basically means, that I want to delete specific functions from them. It is the same function from all java files.

And I want to do that everytime after I compile the Haxe files. So I need automation. I looking into sed, but I am not even sure it can be done with it. I would to find the end of the function somehow.

Or does anyone know another tool suited for this?

Comment: (out of curiosity) Why can't you delete the methods in the haXe code?

Comment: @AnubianNoob I want to delete some functions generated by the haxe compiler that are not part of the haxe code itself.

Comment: If it's the reflection helper functions, you can have the compiler not generate them by annotating your class with `@:nativeGen`

Comment: @waneck that is cool and kind of what i want. But i would habe to the annotation to a lot of classes in libraries.

Comment: You can use a macro that will automatically add this metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get hold of one of the bytecode manipulation package, such as [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/). Read the docs and sample programs. Write a program that automates the code modification you're interested in.